# PHP echo fails to give output when a longer string is echoed

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am implementing keyword search in PHP. When no. of results from DB are greater than 264 PHP echo fails to give any output. Any idea what might be the problem here?

```
// my algo is -
 $result = mysql_query(searchQueryString) or die(mysql_error());
 $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
//Create a $json_array of required values
$str_to_print = json_encode($json_array);
echo $str_to_print;//this gives empty output when no. of rows from DB > 264
//Everything else is working properlycode here
```

Comment: Have you checked error logs? @user3552391

Comment: why don't you use print_r(json_encode($json_array)); and see which string is longer than 264? and why do you need 264 char limit? why are you printing a json_array?

Comment: I have to send that response to client in json format(converted in string).

Comment: You should really look into replacin php mysql code with php mysqli, as it is deprecated since PHP 5.5x and totaly removed from PHP7.
http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please excuse this, I wanted to comment but am unable to due to rep.

I used this statement: `print json_encode(array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));` and got the result of: `[1,2,3,4,5]`.

Either your result from the mysql_query is wrong, or something else is.

Just noticed, you are using this line of code:

```
$str_to_print = json_encode($json_array);
```

But where is `$json_array` set? Is it set at all or are you passing a null pointer to the function? *Error: Notice: Undefined variable: json_array*

Comment: I have not added the whole code. It is just the algo. I am creating $json_array of objects using rows from results coming from DB after executing the query. As I said, Everything else is working fine. Just the length of the string  json_encode($json_array) is affecting the output of echo. why?

Comment: Try using `var_dump(json_last_error_msg()); var_dump(json_last_error());`, could prove to be very useful